# User updated values us not binding to ngModel directive when using jpTimeMask

Tags: html, angular, angular7

I am working in Angular 7 project. I have text input field and I am using jpTimeMask module for masking the input field for entering time.

```
<div><input type="text" jpTimeMask [jpTimeMaskChangeLazy]="false" [(ngModel)]="amPMPush"
                name="FirstName" class="without_ampm textbox"></div>
```

This is the code I am using.

Only default values is appending to the field but the user updated values us not reflecting. Can any one suggest why the new modified values are not binding?